# Flutter error after deleting environment variables

Tags: flutter, environment-variables

I am working on this flutter app with VScode and it worked fine until I deleted some environment variables of my system in order to add a new feature.

This is the error I get:
The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Build completed with 1 failures.
assert pluginDirectory.exists()
| |
| false
C:\Users\er\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\contacts_service-0.6.3\android

I tried several things but no progress. The solution is to add new variables to environment variables but I didn't wrote them. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue related to the cached copy in your pub cache, since the issue is coming from a specific plugin. You could try to do clear your cache with:

`dart pub cache clean`

That will clear out all of your files from the `C:\Users\er\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache` folder, and then when you next use `flutter pub get` to install dependencies you will have a fresh install.

If that doesn't work you could also try to verify that `flutter doctor` returns no issues and that the issue persists after a run of `flutter clean` in your project folder.

Comment: I already tried those commands, it didn't do any changes.